# How to store decrypted sent messages with mutt + pgp?

Tags: email, pgp, mutt

I'm using mutt with PGP and would like to store sent messsages in a corresponding IMAP folder. Problem: When I send an encrypted email to somebody, mutt copies the encrypted email to the sent folder, instead of an unencrypted version. Of course, since it is encrypted with the receivers key, I cannot unencrypt this message anymore, making it useless.

Is there a setting in mutt to fix this?

Comment: I think the standard solution to this issue is to always add yourself as a recipient. This way you wont have to store unencrypted messages and, in the future, you'll be able to decrypt/read what you sent.

Comment: Ah, ok, that could be done. But it will be quite a hassle to make non-mutt email client (e.g., on my phone) recognize the conversation threads. I‘d rather save an unencrypted version in the Sent folder, if possible.

Answer (score 1):

The setting you ask for is `set fcc_clear=yes`. This will save it in cleartext to the Sent folder (see `man muttrc` for full explanation).

There was a question to the opposite on [superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/636705/how-can-you-let-mutt-encrypt-mails-in-the-sent-mail-folder), so I'll extend my answer to that for a full picture.

Depending on where your "Sent" folder resides, either in a remote IMAP server you want to have fulltext search for (probably need cleartext), or on a local disk that is encrypted at-rest, you have further options:

- mutt currently has [pgp_self_encrypt](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/#pgp-self-encrypt) in tandem with [pgp_default_key](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/#pgp-default-key) (added to mutt on 2017-05-29 / 2018-01-15, so check your version) to control the behaviour
- gnupg has an `encrypt-to <keyid>` [option](https://www.gnupg.org/gph/en/manual/r1261.html), but I would prefer the mutt config
- neomutt has [encrypt-to-self](https://neomutt.org/feature/encrypt-to-self)